# ICollection.Where using Func<> causes 'Internal .NET Framework Data Provider error 1025' error

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities, linq-to-objects

Ok, bit stumped here.

I'm trying to pass a `Func<>` as a query and I'm getting **Internal .NET Framework Data Provider error 1025** error:

```
IEnumerable <Results> GetByPredicate(Func<Message, bool> predicate) {
  DataContext.Threads.Where(<some criteria>)
                     .Select(m => m.Messages.Where(predicate));
}

// usage
GetByPredicate(message => message.Delivered == false);
GetByPredicate(message => message.Received == true);
// and so on
```

`m.Messages` shows as `ICollection<Message>` and `m.Messages.Where(predicate)` **refuses to accept `Expression<Func<Message, bool>>`.**

Executing this results in the 1025 error, whereas replacing the predicate inline works fine:

```
IEnumerable <Results> GetByPredicate(Func<Message, bool> predicate) {
  DataContext.Threads.Where(<some criteria>)
                     .Select(m => m.Messages.Where(message => message.Delivered == false));
}
```

Can someone please explain what am I missing?

This is how `Thread`, `Message` entities are defined:

```
public class Thread
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Message> Messages { get; set; }
    ... more props
}

public class Message
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Thread Thread { get; set; }
    ... more props
}
```

Full exception:

> at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.GetLambdaExpression(Expression argument)
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.GetLambdaExpression(MethodCallExpression callExpression, Int32 argumentOrdinal)
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.OneLambdaTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, ref DbExpression source, ref DbExpressionBinding sourceBinding, ref DbExpression lambda)
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.OneLambdaTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call)
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.SequenceMethodTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, SequenceMethod sequenceMethod)
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression linq)
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.OneLambdaTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, ref DbExpression source, ref DbExpressionBinding sourceBinding, ref DbExpression lambda)
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.OneLambdaTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call)
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.SequenceMethodTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, SequenceMethod sequenceMethod)
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression linq)
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.OneLambdaTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, ref DbExpression source, ref DbExpressionBinding sourceBinding, ref DbExpression lambda)
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.OneLambdaTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call)
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.SequenceMethodTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, SequenceMethod sequenceMethod)
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression linq)
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.AggregateTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call)
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.SequenceMethodTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, SequenceMethod sequenceMethod)
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression linq)
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateLambda(LambdaExpression lambda, DbExpression input)
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateLambda(LambdaExpression lambda, DbExpression input, ref DbExpressionBinding binding)
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.OneLambdaTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, ref DbExpression source, ref DbExpressionBinding sourceBinding, ref DbExpression lambda)
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.SelectTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call)
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.SequenceMethodTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, SequenceMethod sequenceMethod)
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression linq)
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.OneLambdaTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, ref DbExpression source, ref DbExpressionBinding sourceBinding, ref DbExpression lambda)
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.SelectTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call)
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.SequenceMethodTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, SequenceMethod sequenceMethod)
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression linq)
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.UnaryTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, UnaryExpression linq)
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.ContainsTranslator.TranslateContains(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression sourceExpression, Expression valueExpression)
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.ContainsTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call)
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.SequenceMethodTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, SequenceMethod sequenceMethod)
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression linq)
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateLambda(LambdaExpression lambda, DbExpression input)
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateLambda(LambdaExpression lambda, DbExpression input, ref DbExpressionBinding binding)
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.OneLambdaTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, ref DbExpression source, ref DbExpressionBinding sourceBinding, ref DbExpression lambda)
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.OneLambdaTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call)
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.SequenceMethodTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, SequenceMethod sequenceMethod)
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression linq)
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.OneLambdaTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, ref DbExpression source, ref DbExpressionBinding sourceBinding, ref DbExpression lambda)
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.SelectTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call)
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.SequenceMethodTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, SequenceMethod sequenceMethod)
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression linq)
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.OneLambdaTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, ref DbExpression source, ref DbExpressionBinding sourceBinding, ref DbExpression lambda)
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.OneLambdaTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call)
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.SequenceMethodTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, SequenceMethod sequenceMethod)
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression linq)
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.UnarySequenceMethodTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call)
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.SequenceMethodTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, SequenceMethod sequenceMethod)
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression linq)
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.Convert()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ELinqQueryState.GetExecutionPlan(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.b__6()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction(Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.b__5()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DefaultExecutionStrategy.Execute(Func`1 operation)
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1..GetEnumerator>b__0()
>   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()    at
>   System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)    at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray(IEnumerable`1 source)    at
>   Data.Helpers.MessageRepository.GetMessageDtos(Int64 userId, Int32 limit, IQueryable`1 messages, Expression`1 orderBy)
>   in MessageRepository.cs: line 201    at
>   Data.Helpers.MessageRepository.GetMessagesByPredicate(Int64 userId, Int32 limit, Int64 newerThan, Int64 olderThan, Expression`1 predicate)
>   in MessageRepository.cs: line 195    at
>   Data.Helpers.MessageRepository.GetUnreadByRecipientMessages(Int64 userId, Int32 limit, Int64 newerThan, Int64 olderThan)
>   in MessageRepository.cs: line 160    at
>   Data.IntegrationTests.MessageRepositoryTests.ShouldReturnUnseenMessagesOnly()
>   in MessageRepositoryTests.cs: line 49

Comment: Is this the full exception?

Comment: Pass `<Expression<Func<Message, bool>>`

Comment: @GertArnold: Tried that already. Edited my question to make it stand out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found an answer - it was clear that ELinq was complaining about a lack of `Expression<...>` and `ICollection.Where` wouldn't accept an `Expression`.

So casting the `ICollection` to `IQueryable` fixes the issue:

```
m => m.Messages.AsQueryable().Where(predicate)  // IQueryable.Where accepts Expressions

// complete invocation
IEnumerable <Results> GetByPredicate(Func<Message, bool> predicate) {
  DataContext.Threads.Where(<some criteria>)
                     .Select(m => m.Messages.AsQueryable().Where(predicate));
}
```

Maybe there's a better answer but this seems to fix the issue for now.